How to get the CS50 'Meal Time' exercise to pass tests
def main():

    time = input("What time is it? ")

    hours, minutes = time.split(":")

    minutesToHours = float(minutes) / 60
    convert(float(hours)+minutesToHours)



def convert(time):

    if 7 <= time <= 8:
          timetoeat = "breakfast time"
    elif 12 <= time <= 13:
         timetoeat = "lunch time"
    elif 18 <= time <= 19:
         timetoeat = "dinner time"

    print(timetoeat)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()



I have done the output needed in this problem but when I checked it in check50 it is mostly poker face that's why I want to improve this but I don't know what to do so can anyone help me to improve my code or advice me something? also cs50 require to use "if name == "main":" even they didn't teach it so I'm wondering if can anyone explain what does this do in simplest form

Look at what the assignment says convert is supposed to do. Look at what your convert does. Your convert does something entirely different from what the assignment says it should do.

What you have implemented for the convert function is not what is requested by the question. The question says it takes a string of "7:30" and return 7.5 hours. This is not what your code does. Your overall functionality looks correct, but you need to restructure what is in main and convert

Thankss Ill keep that in mind

Welcome to CS50!
Note: As this is an educational exercise, this answer is designed to guide the user to the solution, rather than providing an explicit solution.

1) A further explanation of __name__ == '__main__':

There is already an excellent answer posted here.


2) Why does my code not pass the tests?
Note the requirement states in principal: 'The convert function, called by main, "should return 7.5".'
However, your convert function does something completely different. It does not return a value and contains the logic which should be held by main.
Fixes:

The main function must contain the logic to route the time (returned by convert) to the appropriate text output.
The convert function must contain the conversion logic (currently held in main).
The convert function must contain a return statement to return the converted decimal value back to main.

For example:
def main():

    # Prompt user for time.

    # Convert time to a decimal value (call the convert function).

    # Test the returned time as a decimal to determine the text 
    # to be displayed, using your series of 'if' statements.

def convert(time):

    # Parse the time into hours and minutes.

    # Calculate the decimal form of time.

    # Return the calculated value.


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Further suggestions:

When printing the meal time, simply call the print function with the appropriate text within its respective if block. This will either display a meal time if within the given time bounds, or will not print anything if none of the if statements validate. In the case of none of the if statements validating, using a variable (as you have done) will raise a NameError if the variable is not initialised first.

